# How do I mount a harddrive to my /home folder in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, mount, hard-drive

Im wondering how to mount my second HDD to my /home folder like you do in other *NIX systems, making the mount point just that folder and not a standard HDD.

I am aware of the method of copying my /home folder and then telling OSX via System Preferences/Users & Groups to look for the folder in a different location.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to properly mount the entire HDD to become nothing more than my /home. I don't want it to even show up in Finder as an HDD.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying `mount` command is there, so you could use it to mount the disc as part of a script running as boot time. The MacOS boot sequence is a little weird; you'll need to create an item in the /System/StartupItems directory to the [proper specifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/StartupItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW9-105987).